# cancel EntryElement editing in DialogViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a crash performing SendAction from UIButtonItem handler when DialogViewController any of the input fields are being edited

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SendAction(Level2ViewController.mainbutt.Action, Level2ViewController.mainbutt.Target, this, null);
```

Is there a way to programmatically end any field editing in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add this to viewController works?

```
editing = false
```

Comment: is there a way to access current viewController from UIBarButtonItem handler?

Comment: How you added the target of the UIBarButtonItem

Comment: I solved the problem by performing ```NavigationController.View.EndEditing(true);```